# Package an Electron app on an Apple Silicon chip for Windows with Electron Packager

Tags: electron, electron-packager

I'm using Electron Packager to distribute an application created with Electron.
I'm using a Mac with an Apple Silicon chip (M1 to be exact).

The problem is that I also need to distribute this application for Windows x64 and Windows ARM.
However, when trying to run the command below, the following error is always returned `spawn Unknown system error -86`:

```
npx electron-packager . --overwrite --no-prune --icon=./icon/icon.ico --platform=win32 --arch=x64
```

I already installed Wine with brew, but the error persists.